# Building an rdl in Visual Studio 2015 is removing line breaks from my xml code

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, rdl

I'm building RDL files in Visual Studio 2015 for 2008 R2 Schema and the files output in bin\debug don't have line breaks in the XML.  It's all one giant line which makes it a pain for people to read.

Is there some setting that I'm missing to prevent this from happening?  The main RDL file does have the line breaks in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well I didn't figure out a solution in Visual Studio 2015, but I opened it up in Visual Studio 2012 and built it there and since 2010 Schema is the default it did not remove the line breaks from the xml code in the built file.